# Android apk not connecting to Azure server after using proguard

Tags: android, azure, proguard

I have been looking to a solution to this problem, i have tried many proguard configurations without success.
The app runs perfectly until I make the release version with proguard. 
I am getting the error: 
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:The class representing the mobile serviceTable must have a single id property defined" while assigning the class

I belive that is caused by the class of the table that i am trying to reach, having its variable 'id' name changed.

I have the folowing:

```
public class User {
   public String id;
   public String nickname;
   public String phone;
}
```

and the connection is made with:

```
mClient.getTable(User.class).where().field("nickname")
    .eq(nick).execute(new TableQueryCallback<User>() {....
```

the proguard config file is:

```
-keep class com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.core**

-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.os.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask

##---------------from here is the part that i have modified a lot of times -

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.company.app.User.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class com.company.app.User.** { *; }
```

I have tried many modifications for hours without success. 
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628737/android-proguard-enabled-apk-not-connecting-to-azure-server) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476315/how-keep-my-class-from-obfuscate-by-proguard) among many others.

Can you please help me?
Thanks

EDIT: solved. Just remove the .** after User in the proguard file. Leave it like this:

```
-keep public class com.company.app.User { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class com.company.app.User { *; }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the additional SerializedName line to your proguard config as mentioned in one of the linked posts comments?

-keep @interface com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

Comment: Do you mean by putting in the class members  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id") and then adding 
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep @interface com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
?
Yes, i have tried that

Comment: I am checking the proguard files and in mapping.txt i can see 
com.company.app.User -> com.company.app.User:
    java.lang.String nickname -> a
    java.lang.String phone -> b
so those are being obfuscated
and in the usage.txt :
public java.lang.String id
so the id is not kept...I guess that there is the problem

Comment: I solved the problem. Just remove the .** after User in the proguard file and fixed. I can't believe i spent that much time with this thing...

Comment: I'd suggest adding that as an answer and accepting it so the next time someone runs into it, you'll provide them the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

solved. Just remove the .** after User in the proguard file. Leave it like this:

```
-keep public class com.company.app.User { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class com.company.app.User { *; }
```